# Oracle SQL - left join leading to duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Happy Friday to one and all!

I have three tables that I am working with and I am having a tough time with the joins.  Table 1 has fields name, id, state, sales.  Table 2 has state and stateID (among others).  Table 3 has stateID and region (among others).  What I need is the stateID and region fields in Table 1.

What I tried is

```
select name, id, state, stateID, region, sales
from table 1 taba
left join table 2 tabb
on taba.state = tabb.state
left join table 3 tabc
on tabb.stateid = tabc.stateid
```

This took table 1 from ~16k rows to ~100k rows

I tried just my first join by itself and got the correct number of rows.  How do I get rid of these duplicate rows when I do that third join?

```
Table 1 
Name   ID    State        Sales  
John   01    Texas       50,234  
Steve  02    Washington  39,261
Amanda 03    Ohio        67,892

Table 2 
State       StateID
Texas       TX
Washington  WA 
Ohio        OH

Table 3
StateID    Region
TX         South
WA         Northwest
OH         Midwest
```

I need it to look like this:

```
Name   ID    State        StateID   Region   Sales  
John   01    Texas        TX       South     50,234  
Steve  02    Washington   WA       Northwest 39,261
Amanda 03    Ohio         OH       Midwest   67,892
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this statement?  Is `state` unique in table 2?

Comment: Why are you using `LEFT JOIN`s and not `INNER JOIN`s? Are there salespeople without states? or states without regions?

Comment: The query seems correct, this looks very much like a data problem. If each state has no more than one state id, and each state id has no more than one region, then the output should have the same number of rows as the original table. Most definitely you either have duplicates either in the STATE column in the states table or in the STATE_ID in the regions table.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming each state has multiple regions, but there is nothing in table 1 that indicates a region. So when you join to table 3 and there is 100 regions in that state and the only thing you are joining on is a stateID, it will return all 100 regions.

You probably need region in your first table to indicate the region AND state the sale occurred in or you can throw a DISTINCT on the query.

```
select DISTINCT name, id, state, stateID, region, sales
from table 1 taba
left join table 2 tabb
on taba.state = tabb.state
left join table 3 tabc
on tabb.stateid = tabc.stateid
```

Based on your new provided tables and data, this should give you what you want:

```
select name, id, state, stateID, region, SUM(sales) AS sales
    from table1 taba
    left join table2 tabb
    on taba.state = tabb.state
    left join table3 tabc
    on tabb.stateid = tabc.stateid
GROUP BY name, id, state, stateID, region
```

Comment: several states make up a region, not the other way around (ie, utah, colorado, wyoming, montana, idaho, nevada are in the region "mountain west")

Comment: So the state on your record in table 1, does that state have only 1 record in table 2 and table 3?

Comment: sorry, im beginner when it comes to sql, but each state has one stateid and one region.

Comment: Please add the table structure for 1, 2, 3 into your post and add some sample data. It will make this much easier.

Comment: Just added; sorry I dont know how to format, it looked fine when I posted it.

Comment: @dbwhite64 Updated. Should be a straight SUM() as long as each state (like TX) has 1 record in table 2 and each state, again like TX, has one record in table 3.

Comment: As what @dbwhite64 said, as long as there are no duplicates StateID in table 2 & 3, you should get the result as intended. Perhaps you can add sample results you are getting?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Cool username.  Yeah, I got it now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think using this query should do the job.

```
select name, id, state, stateID, region, sales
from table1 natural join table2 natural join table3
```

Because you tables are using the same names for attributes, you can use the natural join (It will only keep the common attributes, assuming that all states in table1 are in table2 and all stateID in table2 are in table3).

And if you need the sum of sales for each name (which is not clear from your question) :

```
select name, id, state, stateID, region, SUM(sales)
from table1 natural join table2 natural join table3
group by name, id, state, stateID, region
```

Comment: `natural join` is an abomination, because it does not even take declared foreign key relationships into account when deciding on the `join` keys.  You should not use it in any queries.

Comment: Thanks or the comment. I am not sure to have really understood what you said, could you explain that ? Does it mean that it will join on every attributes even those with no foreign key relationship ? My point was more on avoiding the use of left join (which seems useless here) and do a inner join (natural join or join on)